# Can't use Android NDK with libGDX

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, libgdx

For a little game project, we have to use the android NDK for include the AI with a shared library, and for the graphics, we use the libgdx.

When I comment the android.ndk section in my build.gradle file, the app works, and when I uncomment it I have an error. I don't know what I can do for resolving it.

build.gradle (android) (i use the google ndk sample project for test)

```
model {
    android {
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"
        compileSdkVersion = 23
    }

//    android.ndk {
//        moduleName = "hello-jni"
//    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.pro"))
        }
    }
//
    android.productFlavors {
        // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
        // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
        create("arm") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi")
        }
        create("arm7") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
        }
        create("arm8") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("arm64-v8a")
        }
        create("x86") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("x86")
        }
        create("x86-64") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("x86_64")
        }
        create("mips") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("mips")
        }
        create("mips-64") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("mips64")
        }
        // To include all cpu architectures, leaves abiFilters empty
        create("all")
    }

    android.sources {
        main {
            manifest {
                source {
                    srcDir "."
                    include "AndroidManifest.xml"
                }
            }
            java {
                source {
                    srcDir "src"
                }
            }
            aidl {
                source {
                    srcDir "src"
                }
            }
            renderscript {
                source {
                    srcDir "src"
                }
            }
            res {
                source {
                    srcDir "res"
                }
            }
            assets {
                source {
                    srcDir "assets"
                }
            }
            jniLibs {
                source {
                    srcDir "libs"
                }
            }
            jni {
                source {
                    srcDir "jni"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() { 
    file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
        if(outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}

task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'eu.epitech.gomokutest.android/eu.epitech.gomokutest.android.AndroidLauncher'
}

// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
eclipse {
    // need to specify Java source sets explicitely, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
    // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
        }
    }

    jdt {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.6
        targetCompatibility = 1.6
    }

    classpath {
        plusConfigurations += [ project.configurations.compile ]        
        containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'       
    }

    project {
        name = appName + "-android"
        natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
        buildCommands.clear();
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
        buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
    }
}

// sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("src");
        scopes = [ COMPILE: [plus:[project.configurations.compile]]]        

        iml {
            withXml {
                def node = it.asNode()
                def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
                builder.current = node;
                builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                    facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                        configuration {
                            option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value:"true")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

build.gradle (Project root)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "GomokuTest"
        gdxVersion = '1.7.1'
        roboVMVersion = '1.9.0'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.6.0'
    }

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "com.android.model.application"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

Error Log

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: eu.epitech.gomokutest.android, PID: 27142
                                                                               java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                                                                                   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1090)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
                                                                                Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load shared library 'gdx' for target: Linux, 32-bit
                                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:118)
                                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxNativesLoader.load(GdxNativesLoader.java:34)
                                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.<clinit>(AndroidApplication.java:61)
                                                                                   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1090) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/eu.epitech.gomokutest.android-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/eu.epitech.gomokutest.android-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/eu.epitech.gomokutest.android-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libgdx.so"
                                                                                   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
                                                                                   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
                                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:113)
                                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxNativesLoader.load(GdxNativesLoader.java:34) 
                                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.<clinit>(AndroidApplication.java:61) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1090) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```